# Get will not work properly under while condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

For some reason… I can't get this simple get method to work. I'm using data attribute to find out where the meta html is located on the server.

```js
var i = 0;


while (i < 1) {
  $('body').find('.div[data-meta]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    var meta = $this.getAttribute("data-meta")

    $.get(meta, function(data) {$('head').append(data);});
    i++;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="div" data-meta="meta.html"></div>
```

Comment: If you are only running the while loop once, you don't need the while loop.

Comment: To start, add `;` after `var $this = $(this)` and `var meta = $this.getAttribute("data-meta")`

Comment: Offtopic: @HamzaAbdaoui meh - makes no difference to anything

Comment: Check your console, you'll see:  `$(...).getAttribute is not a function`  - you're mixing your jquery objects with DOM nodes.  Either use `var meta = this.getAttribute("data-meta")` *or* `var meta = $(this).data("meta")`.  Learn to use the browser console / debugger.  Check what value you get for `var meta` - that's where the issue is, not the `get`.

Comment: The reason why I use while is because at one point… I got it to work some how, but it kept running indefinitely and crashed my computer and lost how I did it because it didn't save.

Comment: But with the while condition… I know it'll only run once

Comment: I have no clue what I did to make it work… I accidentally typed something… and it magically worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;

$(function(){
$('body').find('.div[data-meta]').each(function() {
  var meta = $(this).data('meta');
  console.log(meta)
  });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-meta="meta.html"></div>
```

it works... try it now.

Comment: Please add some comments to describe what you've changed and why it works / why the original did not work.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: For completeness: `var meta = $this.attr("data-meta");` (jQuery) also works, as does `var meta = this.getAttribute("data-meta");` (pure javascript)